# SPY боты, как от них уходить

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажите как определить ботов SPY сервисов. Как их можна забанить

Comment: я использую технологию невыкладывания секретного кода наружу :)

Comment: Можешь подсказать как ты это делаешь)

Comment: ну просто не выкладывай свой код в интернет, если не хочешь, чтоб его кто-то увидел :)

Comment: а вообще, чем они тебе мешают и где ты их нашёл? :)

Comment: рекламирую товар уникальный ленд. Не хочу чтоб ленд украли. На ленд переходят через баннер. Хочу ботов либо блочить либо отправлять на др сайт.

Comment: Ясно. Ленд может и человек украсть :(

Answer (score 1):

Создай `robots.txt` в корне сайта, а внутри напиши следующее:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Говорит добропорядочным ботам не ходить по сайту.
Недобропорядочных ботов никак не уговорить этого не делать :)